# How can I remove correlated noise spikes from 2 signals?

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, signal-processing, correlation, noise

I have some MRI data collected across time.  When the patient moves, this results in a spike in the signal (so I guess it's not really "noise").  I would like to identify and remove these.  So far I have been removing based on the local median and it works pretty well for the big spikes, but I'd like to do better.

I noticed that if I measure the signal in 2 places in the image, some of the noise will be correlated between the 2 signals (e.g., at some time point, both signals show an upward spike of about the same size), while some of it does not appear correlated.  It would make sense that spikes due to motion would be correlated, because the motion would affect the whole image.  Is there a way I can exploit the apparent correlation to remove these points from the signals?  I don't know where to start.  Thanks for any tips.

An example of the signals:

[image: signals]

Comment: A better site for this question is [dsp.se]

Answer (score 0):

Yes the topic that you are talking about is in the area of robust statistics. Have a look at my previous answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272552/correctness-of-a-statistical-evaluation-of-a-parameter/1287180#1287180). You may want to check robust statistics for correlated data. But it is about the correlation of the data over time. In indeed there is correlation between two signals a short time [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) should tell this.

Answer (score 0):

Before you bring in the heavy artillery I suggest you do two simple things.

1. Make sure the two signals are time-aligned. Pick a prominent peak from signal 1, then find the corresponding peak in signal 2, and calculate the offset between the two signals by visual inspection.
2. After time-alignment, pick four or five prominent peaks from signal 1, and plot both signal 1 and 2 in the range from, say, -50 to 50 around each peak. That will give you a good impression of whether the two signals are disturbed to a similar extent.

You should certainly try to zoom in on the peaks. I don't know what the sampling frequency is but if the cause of the disturbance is that the patient is moving I would expect it to look more like a smeared-out section than a peak, and if that is the case a median filter is not the best solution.