# compare sample mean and sample median as estimators of µ

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

> Under symmetry, $F^{−1}
> (0.5) = E(X)$. Compare the sample mean as an estimator of µ
>   to that of the sample median ($F^{−1}
> (0.5)$) for n sufficiently large, assuming that
>   $X_i$ ∼ Z = N(0, 1), i = 1, . . . , n, iid.

I know that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of µ, but I'm not sure how to deal with the sample median. It seems the sample median is also unbiased as an estimator of µ, then what should I do to compare them? Can anyone give some hints? Thanks.

Comment: Median has a higher asymptotic variance - by a factor of [$\frac \pi 2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Sampling_distribution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes here are some hints:

Sample mean is the maximum likelihood estimator if the data at hand follows a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). On the other hand, sample median is the maximum likelihood estimator of the mean if the data follows a [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).

In your question the mean and the median are the same. So both estimators will be able to approach to the true parameter, as long as there are enough data samples, i.e. for large $n$.

> Given two unbiased estimators which one is better?

The one which has the lowest variance and hence the lowest **mean squared error (MSE)**.

**Added:** Regarding Batman's comment, one may want to see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272552/correctness-of-a-statistical-evaluation-of-a-parameter/1287180#1287180) as well.

Comment: Okay I'll just go ahead and compare their MSE! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't say that lowest variance is necessarily makes one estimator the best; you need to define best based on your application (e.g. robustness may be more important). The sample mean and sample median are both unbiased estimates of $\mu$, but the median has a much higher breakdown point (0.5) than the mean (0), meaning one sample can throw off the estimate of $\mu$ for the mean but half the samples are needed for median.

Comment: @Batman you are right and I know all that stuff. But when you read the question do you think robustness is a part of the question?